# How can I set up my Github Account to work in each terminal session?

Tags: terminal, git, github

Every time I want to clone one of my repos, I have to enter my Github account name and access token. How can I add my github account to my terminal?

Comment: Have you tried the [GitHub CLI auth method?](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login)

Answer (score 1):

If you trust the machine you are on (ie no one else has access to it, no remote admins, no remote backups, etc) then you can use the relatively insecure "store" credential helper.

In `$HOME/.gitconfig` add the section

```
[credential]
        helper = store
```

Now in `$HOME/.git-credentials` you can add an entry such as

```
https://GIT_USER_NAME:GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN@github.com
```

Now all access to https://github.com/repo/name will use that username and access token.

If you are using `ssh` to access github then you can use standard ssh keys (you need to upload the public key - see the official documentation at https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh).

Now you can create a `$HOME/.ssh/config` entry such as

```
Host github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/gitkey
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  ForwardAgent no
```

Now repo's accessed as `git@github.com:repo/name` will use that key for access (which can be accessed via `ssh-agent` if you don't want to type the passphrase each time!)